# When is the Radon-Nikodym derivative (essentially) bounded?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu\lll\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite Borel measures, which are not *finite*, on a topological space $X$.  Under what conditions is $0<\operatorname{esssup}(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu})<\infty$?

**Hypothesis:** Is this only possible when the measures are finite?

**Edit:** 
As it was pointed out, the finiteness of $\nu$ and $\mu$ is not enough.

Comment: It holds if and only if $\mu$ is not the zero measure and there exists a finite constant $M$ such that $\mu(A) \le M \nu(A)$ for all measurable $A$.  We might write $\mu \le M\nu$ for short. Is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed.  Do you have a reference?  

Also, I assume the localized version, would be iff there is an $L^{\infty}_{\nu,loc}$ function $f$ for which $\mu(A\cap K)\leq \|f I_K\|_{\infty} \nu(A \cap K)$ for every Borel set $A$ and every compact set $K$?

Comment: Sure, if you like, though that condition seems harder to check.  I might say: for every $K$ there exists $M_K$ such that $\mu(A) \le M_K \nu(A)$ for all measurable $A \subset K$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  Is this a studied property or is it not a thing?

Comment: I don't have a reference offhand, though it might be in Folland, but the equivalence is a fairly easy exercise.  (For the backward direction, the Radon-Nikodym theorem asserts that $d\mu/d\nu$ exists, and if you consider the set $A = \{d\mu/d\nu > M\}$, you can show that $\nu(A)=0$.)  This property does come up sometimes and, as I mentioned, is commonly notated as $\mu \le M\nu$.

Comment: I think you can also show it suffices to have $\mu(A) \le M\nu(A)$ for all $A$ in some $\pi$-system which generates the $\sigma$-algebra.  For instance, all open $A$, or all closed $A$.  This might need $\nu$ to be finite, I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: This sounds interesting.  I'll have to think about it; I haven't used $\pi$ systems since my younger days so this should be fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has any relation with the measures being finite or not. For instance take $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, $\nu$ the Lebesgue measure, and $\mu=2\nu$. Then $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=2$.

You can always look at the problem the opposite way: given a measure $\nu$ and any non-negative $g\in L^\infty(X)$, you can define 
$$
\mu(E)=\int_E g\,d\nu.
$$
If $\nu$ is infinite, $\mu$ will be infinite precisely when $g\not\in L^1(X,\nu)$.

Comment: But in your example, $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}<\infty$ so the measure's essential supremum is finite...

Comment: What is the essential supremum of a measure?

Comment: What measure do you mean?  $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is a measurable function, so it's essential supremum is well-defined.

Comment: Yes,and  I have no idea what you are talking about. Your question was "is this only possible when the measures are finite"? And I gave you an example of two $\sigma$-finite Borel measures, which are not finite, and with bounded RN derivative. If that's not what you want, you may have to rephrase your question to mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: You're right, it's my bad, I'll accept the answer.